# AWSCLI aggregate results from multiple cli invocations

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm using AWSCLI on Windows to start, query and connect to instances via RDP.  I have three values I want to return in a single query, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Can you demonstrate how to do it?

Here are the three values returned in three queries:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id i-xxxxxxxx --query InstanceStatuses[*].InstanceState.Code
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id i-xxxxxxxx --query InstanceStatuses[*].SystemStatus.Status
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id i-xxxxxxxx --query InstanceStatuses[*].InstanceStatus.Status
```

The output looks like this:

```
{
"InstanceStatuses": [
    {
        "InstanceId": "i-1234567890abcdef0",
        "InstanceState": {
            "Code": 16,
            "Name": "running"
        },
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1d",
        "SystemStatus": {
            "Status": "ok",
            "Details": [
                {
                    "Status": "passed",
                    "Name": "reachability"
                }
            ]
        },
        "InstanceStatus": {
            "Status": "ok",
            "Details": [
                {
                    "Status": "passed",
                    "Name": "reachability"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

and is documented here: [describe-instance-status](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-status.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request more than one attribute in the --query parameter. For example:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status \
    --instance-id i-01122233344455566 \
    --query "InstanceStatuses[0].{code:InstanceState.Code,sstatus:SystemStatus.Status,istatus:InstanceStatus.Status}"
```

This will result in something like:

```
{
   "istatus": "ok",
   "code": 16,
   "sstatus": "ok"
}
```

Note the following changes:

- retrieving InstanceStatuses[0] rather than InstanceStatuses[*]
- multiple values requested within braces
- use of aliases istatus, code, sstatus (feel free to change these)

Comment: Ran out of time...

(1) The InstanceStatuses[0] retrieves the first set of results, correct?  In this case, because we specify a single instance-id, it wouldn't matter? Or is efficiency an issue?

(2) The addition of braces {} - does that group the output into an array, ie, a single, multi-value result?

(3) The aliases, I read somewhere that these are mandatory.  True?

(4) So the trick is to enclose multiple requests in braces, specify them as key:value pairs, where key is a label, and separate the fields by commas?  That's all there is to it?

Thanks very much, this is a big help.

Comment: That's a lot of questions in one comment, but yes. If this answers your question, please accept it so we know that you do not need more help.